# bootstrap 4 dropdown menu extending in screen

Tags: html, css

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <i
    class="far fa-user-circle ml-4"
    type="button"
    data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-expanded="false"
    style="font-size:36px"></i>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Change Password</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to fit the dropdown menu inside the screen

Comment: flex property in header may affect dropdown-menu, provide html of header with dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown do not have the .dropdown-menu-right, if you want to align your dropdown at the right please add this class 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment